# PHP Combining arrays after foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i have products that belong to categories and i need to get such categories and output them as a single array. This is my this code:

```
    $act_prod = array(0=>1,1=>10);
    $active_cat = array();

    foreach ($act_prod as $act) {
        $cat = $this->getDi()->productTable->load($act);
        $active_cat[$act] = $cat->getCategories(); 
    } 

    print_r($active_cat);
```

Which will output:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) )
```

This means product 1 belongs to category 1 and product 10 to category 2 but i dont need all that. I only need the categories like this: Array (1, 2) or Array (0=>1, 1=>2).

What should i use so i get the correct output?

Thank you.

Comment: Is product relates with the single category always ?

Comment: Products can have more than one category.

Comment: Your `$cat->getCategories();` is returning an array. Hence, each key in your `$active_cat` contains an array

Comment: @CainNuke - In that case how should your expected array will look ?

Comment: It can either look like this: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )  or like this: Array (1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code to build up just the list you want.

```
$act_prod = array(0=>1,1=>10);
$active_cat = array(); // will be a flat list of categories

foreach ($act_prod as $act) {
    $cat = $this->getDi()->productTable->load($act);
    foreach($cat->getCategories as $category) {
        // if we have not seen this category on any previous category, push it
        if(!in_array($cat->getCategories(), $active_cat)) {
            array_push($active_cat, $cat->getCategories()); 
        }
    }
} 

// if desired, sort array first
print_r($active_cat);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($act_prod as $act) {
    $cat = $this->getDi()->productTable->load($act);
    $cats = $cat->getCategories(); 

    foreach($cats as $cat)
    {
         $active_cat[] = $cat['cat_id'];
    }
}
```

Assuming `cat_id` is your `category id`

Comment: this solution will leave duplicates in the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten the `$active_cat` array, like this:

```
// ...
foreach ($cat->getCategories() as $category) {
    $active_cat[] = $category;
}
// ...
```

Afterwards, make sure there are no duplicates:

```
$active_cat = array_unique($active_cat);
```